# C# method returns a list of object

Tags: c#, collections

I'm new to C#, so I apologize in advance if this question is inappropriate.

I have a method with the following code:

```
if (activeReservation != 0) 
{
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
    da.Fill(dt);    
    con.Close();
    List<Reservation> resList = new List<Reservation>();
    resList = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
               select new Reservation()
               {
                   roomType = dr["Room Type"].ToString(),
                   roomNumber = dr["Room Number"].ToString(),
                   date = dr["Date"].ToString(),
                   time = dr["Time"].ToString(),
                   numStudents = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Number of Students"]),
                   duration = dr["Duration"].ToString(),
               }).ToList(); 
}
```

What would be the return type of this method if I want to return the list of object *resList* ?

Comment: It's a `List<Reservation>` ? You don't need `List<Reservation> resList = new List<Reservation>();` but just `return (from ... ).ToList();` or eventually `var query = from ... ; return query.ToList();` (query or items or anything eloquent) 

Comment: My answer is correct as per the question , please up vote it

Comment: @NigelAng That: List<Reservation>. [C# MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp) | [Level 0](https://w3schools.in/csharp-tutorial) | [Level 1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/index.htm) | [Level 2](https://tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-tutorials) | [Level 3](https://guru99.com/c-sharp-tutorial.html) | [Level 4](https://geeksforgeeks.org/csharp-programming-language) | [Linq 1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/linq/index.htm) | [Linq 2](https://www.webtrainingroom.com/linq) | Beginning Visual C# 2008 Programming | Professional C# 7 and .Net Core 2.0

Comment: Sorry, my knowledge about method is still really lacking as I just got started and I'm working on winforms. Appreciate the help everyone.

Comment: @NigelAng: fyi: you don't need to open or close the connection with [`SqlDataAdaper.Fill`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dataadapter.fill?view=net-5.0#System_Data_Common_DataAdapter_Fill_System_Data_DataSet_), the method will open and close it autromatically for you: "If the connection is closed before Fill is called, it is opened to retrieve data, then closed. If the connection is open before Fill is called, it remains open."

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks for the heads up! Actually there are other code in this method I just took a portion of it

Comment: By the way, do you know how I can use the returned resList in the original method which called this method? i.e. var x = getResData() . But i don't know what is the data type for it.

Comment: Better to get rid of the `SqlDataAdapter` & `DataTable`. No need to populate a `DataTable` then create a `List<Reservation>`. Replace them with [`SqlCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) & [`SqlDataReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) to read directly from the DB, create new `Reservation` object as you read, and add it to `resList`. See the examples in the doc.

Comment: @NigelAng: It seems you still haven't understood what methods or types are. No offense, but you should really take a step back and read some tutorials. Then you will understand it and don't need to ask such questions. (what type you think could `var x` be if `getResData` returns a `List<Reservation>`?)

Comment: @TimSchmelter damn  my bad. I tried List<T> x but it gave me an error. I forgot I had declared another variable of the same name.

Comment: Maybe you should read more about [Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics). `List<T>` is the type of the generic list where you can store anything and `List<Reservation>` is a concrete list of reservations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return the whole list of resList, *then return the list itself*:

```
public List<Reservation> Reservations()
{
    List<Reservation> resList = new List<Reservation>();
    if (activeReservation != 0) 
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
        da.Fill(dt);    
        con.Close();
        resList = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
               select new Reservation()
               {
                   roomType = dr["Room Type"].ToString(),
                   roomNumber = dr["Room Number"].ToString(),
                   date = dr["Date"].ToString(),
                   time = dr["Time"].ToString(),
                   numStudents = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Number of Students"]),
                   duration = dr["Duration"].ToString(),
               }).ToList(); 
     }

     return resList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The return type of this method should be

```
List<Reservation>
```

And method should return `resList`